# Show combinatorially that $S$ freely generates $\langle S\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometric-group-theory

Let $S = \{b^nab^{-n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, $S$ freely generates $\langle S\rangle$.

The definition I have of freely generates is: $F$ is freely generated by a subset $S\subset F$ if for any group $\Gamma$ and any map $\phi:S\to \Gamma$ we can uniquely extend this to a homomorphism $\varphi:F\to S$.

I think this is essentially trivial but I'm not too comfortable with using this definition yet so would like to check. If $\phi(b^nab^{-n}) = g_n\in\Gamma$ I would just extend this multiplicatively to a homomorphism on $\langle S\rangle$ and then conclude immediately. I don't really see that there's anything at all that needs to be done here?

I'm sure I'm over simplifying it so any pointers would be excellent!

Comment: I really don't know what exactly "prove combinatorially" could mean here, though all this stuff is dealt with in Combinatorial Group Theory. Perhaps you mean that we would have to show that any (normally) reduced  word in the $\;b^nab^{-n}\,'$s isn't the trivial element unless we have the word of length zero...?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah this is also what's thrown me, I think it may have been said so that no topological arguments were used - e.g. looking at the fundamental group of the Cayley graph or something.

The question verbatim is: "Show (combinatorially) that
$\langle S\rangle$ is freely generated by S. Deduce that $\langle S\rangle$ is not f.g."

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen ah yes of course, I've edited the original post now.

Comment: If you don't see that there's anything at all that needs to be done, check if your method would also suggest that $S$ freely generates $\langle S\rangle$ if $S=\{\,a^n:n\in\Bbb N\,\}$.

Comment: Well, the last part of the original question, which you didn't write in your original post, perhaps clears this up (at least a little, I believe): if you show that for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\,,\,\,\left\{b^kab^{-k}\right\}_{k=1}^n\;$ are *free* generators, then clearly $\;S\;$ isn't f.g., and maybe they do mean what I wrote in my past comment...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen okay that actually helps a lot, so I'd need to in fact show that this map is firstly a well defined homomorphism and further show uniqueness?

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry for omitting this part of the question, I thought it would be a simple consequence so wasn't necessary to include. I guess showing what you said in your first post proves that the extension $\varphi$ is well defined and unique so the result follows?

Comment: @user291678 Well, yes. Still though, it should be proved that those are **actually** free generators, meaning: no non-empty word in those letter can be the trivial element of the group. Take as a lame instance the generators $\;\{a, b^{-1}, ba^{-1}\}\;$ . These three elements undoubtedly generate a (free, of course) subgroup of the free group $\;F(a,b)\;$ , but those three generators are **not free ones** since, for example with the reduced word $\;w(x,y,z):=xyz\;$ , we get $\;w(a,b^{-1},ba^{-1})=ab^{-1}ba^{-1}=1\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: "Prove combinatorially" or "show combinatorially" almost certainly means something like this.

Denote $c_n = b^n a b^{-n}$ and $C = \{c_n \,|\, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Given a word $w$ in the elements of $C$, let $\bar w$ denote the element of the free group $\langle a,b \rangle$ obtained by multiplying out the letters of the word $w$. For example, if $w = c_1 c_2$ then $\bar w = (bab^{-1})(b^2ab^{-2}) = babab^{-2}$.

Prove that if $w$ is a nontrivial reduced word in the elements of $C$ then $\bar w$ is a nontrivial element of the group $\langle a,b \rangle$.